# Fetch and display lists of an user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte, sveltekit

I have a profile page that displays the user info. The page shows the user name / email and a button to create a list.

[image]

I can also edit the name and email correctly, and it reflects in the firebase instantaneously. Ok. I get the user data and I can edit it.

What I'm trying to do now is to show the lists that the user has created.

Look, this user has created one list, and what is returned to me is that he doesn't have lists.

[image]

I'll try to shorten the code as much as possible:

```js
<script>
    imports.....
  import { db } from '../../firebase.config.js'


let listings = []

let auth = getAuth()

    // fetch the user's listings
  
    const fetchUserListings = async () => {
  
        const listingsRef = collection(db, 'listings')

        const q = query(
            listingsRef,
            where('userRef', '==', auth.currentUser.uid),
            orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        )

        const querySnap = await getDocs(q)

        querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
            return listings.push({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })
        })
    }

    fetchUserListings()
  
</script>

        <!-- display the user's listings -->
    

<div>

        {#if listings.length > 0}
            <p class="listingText">My lists</p>
            {#each listings as listing}
                <ListingItem listing={listing.data} id={listing.id} />
            {/each}
        {:else}
            <p class="noListings">You have no lists</p>
        {/if}

</div>
```

My ListItem component:

```js
<script>
    export let listing
    export let id
    export let handleDelete
    import DeleteIcon from '../../static/assets/svg/deleteIcon.svg'
</script>

<li class="categoryListing">
    <a href={`/category/${listing.type}/${id}`} class="categoryListingLink">
        <img src={listing.imgUrls[0]} alt={listing.name} class="categoryListingImg" />
        <div class="categoryListingDetails">
            <p class="categoryListingLocation">
                {listing.location}
            </p>
            <p class="CategoryListingName">
                {listing.name}
            </p>
            <p class="categoryListingPrice">
                ${listing.offer ? listing.discountedPrice : listing.regularPrice}
                {listing.type === 'rent' ? '/ por mês' : ''}
            </p>
            <div class="categoryListingInfoDiv">
                <img src="/assets/svg/bedIcon.svg" alt="cama" />
                <p class="categoryListingInfoText">
                    {listing.bedrooms > 1 ? `${listing.bedrooms} camas` : `${listing.bedrooms} cama`}
                </p>
                <img src="/assets/svg/bathtubIcon.svg" alt="banheiro" />
                <p class="categoryListingInfoText">
                    {listing.bathrooms > 1
                        ? `${listing.bathrooms} banheiros`
                        : `${listing.bathrooms} banheiro`}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {#if handleDelete}
        <DeleteIcon
            class="removeIcon"
            fill="rgb(231, 76, 60)"
            onClick={() => {
                handleDelete(listing.id, listing.name)
            }}
        />
    {/if}
</li>
```

Just when you think you've reached the simplest part, it's still tough.

**Update:**

I think that the problem is in firebase. The "docs" are empty:

[image]

Now I am in serious trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
  return listings.push({
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
  })
})
```

I see two things here. The less important: The [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method returns `undefined`, so the `return` is redundant. The more important: the `.push()` alone won't automatically trigger updates. Have a look at [this](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive) section in the Docs
Did you try logging `listings`? I assume the data is there, it's just not displayed, so I propose to change this part to

```
querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
  listings = [...listings, {
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
  }]
})
```

or

```
querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
  listings.push({
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
  })
  listings = listings
})
```

Comment: It's funny because it should work. When I log ```querySnap``` I get a bunch of data, but, when I log ```listings```, I get an empty array.

Comment: All my code is here, firebase works, but doesn't work when I need to get the user's list https://svelte.dev/repl/3427332ea0284208a62140a8c949e46a?version=3.44.3

Comment: I just tried in this simplified [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/244debe0d60243cb8204577482362b99?version=3.44.1) with my config and testdata without a problem

Comment: The problem is that the firebase is not returning the docs from the user. I don't know why. ```docs: Array(0)```

Comment: What if you log `auth.currentUser.uid` before the query? That's defined at that time?

Comment: @RicardodePaula did you try varying the query to a different collection and parameters?

Comment: I replace userRef for user, that's the field in my database. Now I get the docs and the listings arrays with the data

Comment: Happy to have helped and that it works now! :-) Thanks for the Check and upvote!! I just remember that there was another thing I noticed in your code in the Repl ~ if I'm not missing some logic, it looked like that instead of handling the `on:input={handleName}` on the inputs for name and email you might instead simply add `bind:` to the value `bind:value={formData.name}` Not much a difference, but a bit less code in the end...